# How to put a literal percent sign (%) inside F#'s printf format strings?

Tags: .net-4.0, f#, printf, f#-3.1

I want to print a % sign using F#'s printfn function. After [googling the format syntax](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/), this should do the trick: `printfn "%%"`. Apparently not...

F# interactive output:

```
> printfn "%%";;
%%
val it : unit = ()
```

Weird...

I'm using F#3.1 and .NET 4.5, the F# interactive session uses .NET 4.0. Same thing.

For reference: `printfn "%"` doesn't compile (missing format specifier) and `printfn "%s" "%"` is my current workaround...

---

**Update:**

When I change the target F# runtime from 3.1 to 3.0, it works. Is this a bug in the 3.1 runtime?

Comment: I can't repro. It prints `%` for me (also using v3.1).

Comment: Seems to be working for me too: http://pastebin.com/iz6yWzMR but I think this might have been a bug in earlier version - what's your exact version of FSI? (Mine prints "12.0.30110.0")

Comment: My version of FSI is 12.0.21005.1; http://pastebin.com/HdYtULG6 But compiling it into an exe doesn't work, either...

Comment: FWIW, It works on dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bhg9b5

Comment: Oh wow. When I change to F# 3.0 in the project settings, it works. This seems to be a F# 3.1-only thing...

Comment: I noticed I don't have VS2013 Update 2 installed on my machine. I'm going to update now to see if this fixes things in case it's just an old bug like Tomas mentioned...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `printfn "%%"` outputs two percent signs (`%%`) instead of one percent sign (`%`), then you have to [update](http://fsharp.org/use/windows/) F# 3.1 to at least version 3.1.1.

If you are using Visual Studio 2013, you can do this via Tools → Extensions and Updates → Updates → Visual Studio Gallery → Visual FSharp Tools.